# Query for sanitized single quotes in MySQL database.

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When inserting names into a customer database I used the MySQLi function real_escape_string to sanitize the data. An example entry with a single quote now looks like this:

```
Baker\'s Pharmacy
```

However when I try to query for the name using a query such as:

```
$search = "Baker's Pharmacy";
$searchName = $db->real_escape_string($search);
$query = "SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE Name = '$searchName'";
```

I return no matches, what is the correct way to search for santised single quotes?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try `$search = "Baker\\\'s Pharmacy";`  and not use `real_escape_string`

Comment: The *correct* way would be to store the actual data and not a modified version of the data, and search for the actual data that you're looking for.  You should be using query parameters to treat input as values instead of manually sanitizing input before executing it as code.

Comment: It should be `Baker's Pharmacy` without slashes. It seems you escaped your data twice.

Comment: @Your Common Sense Good Point!

Comment: There is only one real_escape_string that runs on data entry is there anything else that could sanitize the input? Magic quotes are definitely off.

Comment: I just worry about SQL injections if I don't sanitize the data on the way into the database.

Comment: @JamesBuckland: SQL injections occur because input is treated as *executable code*.  If you use query parameters and always treat input as *values* (instead of executable code) then it's not a problem.

Comment: @JamesBuckland despite what you think the facts are clear: you have **double** escaping. The sooner you admit the facts the sooner you'll be able to move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two wrong assumptions that needs to be cleared up.

1. Whatever `*escape_string` function **does not sanitize anything**. that's just a nasty rumor that PHP folks are better to finally get rid of.
2. anyway, by using this function, you are formatting your data not for a database but for the SQL query only. All slashes are stripped off by a database and the data gets stored as is.

Instead of "sanitizing" you have to use mysqli prepared statements for both insert and select queries, and you will see not a single problem related to quotes (unless there are magic_quotes or their home-brewed equivalent are hanging around).

Comment: I use both prepared queries and esacpe_string for the data input so that would explain the backslash appearing in the database, is there a query I can run to remove the existing slashes from the database as there are too many to remove manually.

Comment: Well, thats the case. esacpe_string is superfluous here and the very cause of your problem. Unfortunately, I don't know a ready-made query to clean up your data. may be ask another question in this very regard

Comment: I managed to write a small PHP script to fix the issue, thanks for all the help! A case of being too careful.